# Как передать сессию на определенный поддомен?

Tags: сессия, php

На example.com/session.php создается сессия и запихиваются данные,
`$_SESSION['name'] = 'MyName';`

А теперь нужно передать этот MyName на определенный поддомен, именно на 1 поддомен, например subdomain.example.com

К тому же в example.com/session.php после запихивания данных производится redirect на subdomain.example.com/somepage с помощью

```
header('Location: subdomain.example.com/somepage');
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант делать редирект и с POST данными со страницы A на страницу B. Но это возможно с помощью форм и JavaScript. Таким образом, можно в твоем случае на странице, на которой находится `header()` сделать форму типа:

```
<form action='subdomain.example.com/somepage' method='post' name='frm'>
<?php
    foreach ($_SESSION as $a => $b) {
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='".htmlentities($a)."' value='".htmlentities($b)."'>";
    }
?>
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.frm.submit();
</script>
```

А, уже не странице B ( которая `subdomain.example.com/somepage` ) забирать обратно данные в сессию, например:

```
<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $a => $b) {
        $_SESSION[$a] = $b
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант - хранить сессию в БД. К примеру у Codeigniter, есть такая вещь: создаете тыблицу `ci_session` и работаете с ним.

Поддомен тоже может работать с этой базой.